# Below program is terminating abnormally when comparing strings why?

Tags: c, string, data-structures

I am comparing two arrays of string but the program is terminating abnormally after comparing some strings:

[image: output of program]

What is wrong with my code?

```
int main() 
{

    int N,Q;
    printf("Enter no. of strings:");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    char *a[N],*b[Q],k[50],*p;
    int len;

    //scanning first array of strings
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",k);
        len=strlen(k);
        p=(char*)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(p,k);
        a[i]=p;
    }
    printf("no. of Query:");
    scanf("%d",&Q);

    //scanning second array of strings
    for(int i=0;i<Q;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",k);
        len=strlen(k);
        p=(char*)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(p,k);
        b[i]=p;
    }

    ***//comparing both the arrays of strings***
    for(int i=0;i<Q;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            int i=strcmp(a[j],b[i]);
            printf("%d\t",i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why so many question marks ?

Comment: `char *b[Q];` must after `scanf("%d",&Q);`

Comment: i attched output image.

Comment: `int i=strcmp(a[j],b[i]);` --> `int k=strcmp(a[j],b[i]);` Use another variable for result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign strcmp's result into different variable name instead of **'i'** because "i" is your outer loop variable but i of `b[i]` is in stack

```
for(int i=0;i<Q;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        int i=strcmp(a[j],b[i]); 
        printf("%d\t",i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @Clifford `i` of `b[i]` is not outer variable.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : deleted comment - doh!  The code has this and other problems.

Answer (score 3):

At the declaration of `b[Q]` `Q` is initialised - anything could happen after then.  You will nee to at least move the declaration of `b[]` until after you have assigned `Q`.

There may be other issues - that's just the obvious one.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking input the number of string and not using it properly. You should use dynamic memory allocation. Using **malloc**

```
printf("Enter no. of strings:");
scanf("%d",&N);
```

and

```
char *a[N]
```

where as it should be

```
a = malloc(sizeof(char*) * N);
```

and free it before returning to avoid memory leek. `I am not sure that this is the problem but this can be a step in the right direction.`

EDIT based on @Clifford comment: The C99 standard allow this so if your compiler supports C99 this is not an issue.

Comment: I doubt that this is the problem, in C99 variable length arrays (VLA) are valid.  Although in this this instance of user entry without maximum checks probably ill-advised.  The VLA `b[Q]` with Q unitialised is of greater concern.